# I want to delete a line in a file, here's my code

Tags: c++

I want to delete a line in a file, here's my code, it doesn't work, but I can't figure out why after my long time carefully check.

```
/* A function to delete the pointed record. */

void S_O::delete_record (const string &id) {

  /* Read all records in a vector. */
  Temp_Info();

  /* Find the excat record. */
  vector<string>::iterator iter = std::find (temp_info.begin(), temp_info.end(), id);
  /* If find, then delete it. */
  if (iter != temp_info.end())
    temp_info.erase(iter);

  /* Re-input the records in file. */
  ofstream file;

  file.open ("StudentInfo");

  if (!file) {
      cerr << "error: unable to open input file: "
           << "file" <<endl;
  }
  for (size_t i = 0; i != temp_info.size(); i++)
    file << temp_info[i] << endl;

  /* Clear the vector. */
  temp_info.erase (temp_info.begin(), temp_info.end());

}
```

Here is the sample file:

```
姓名（Name） 学号（Id） 性别（Sex） 成绩（Score）
黄佳敏       1         女         100
李佳惠       2         女         100
```

And here is the function:
        inline void S_O::Temp_Info() {

```
  /* Create a stream and a file. */
  ifstream afile ("StudentInfo");

  /* Test if the file is opened successfully. */
  if (afile.is_open()) {
    while (afile.good()) {
      string line;

      /* To read file line to line. */
      while (getline(afile, line)) {
        /* To put lines into a vector. */
        temp_info.push_back(line);
      }
    }

    /* Close the stream and save the file. */
    afile.close();
  }
}
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Don't know. What is it doing? Are you getting an error? Is your program crashing? Is it deleting all or nothing? Or the wrong words?

Comment: @moranhgirl: did you tried to debug it?

Comment: Could be many things: where does `temp_info` come from? Don't you have a read handle on the same file that hasn't been closed yet? Does case matter?

Comment: What is the value of id? and compare the value of it against the data read in temp_info

Comment: @moranhgirl, my suggestion would be to try to put yourself outside your problem, and see if you can understand it; we are in that position. Then, edit it until we can understand it.

Comment: temp_info is a vector I define in the head file.

Comment: Okay. What is the value stored in it?

Comment: I want to read the file line to line into the vector, do the operator on the vector and rewrite vector into file.

Comment: @thefourtheye 'Cause the program is a student manage system. So the 'id' here is the student's id. This function is to find the student's information by id and delete it.

Comment: Can you please edit the question and add the input file and the id passed to delete_record function, in the question?

Comment: You are reading the complete line and storing it in the vector. So, now, temp_info has `姓名 学号 性别 成绩`, `黄佳敏       1         女         100` and `李佳惠       2         女         100`. If you are searching for "1" or "2" in that vector, it will not match. Getting it?

Comment: you are storing the full line in the file but id you are looking for is the full line or the student id?? so find wont work

Comment: @bapu sethi Oh...I thought it will find in the string...Then that's my misunderstand of find...Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should define a struct for the student records and read the data into this struct. Then you can use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_if) and a functor to search for the id:

```
struct find_by_id : std::unary_function<student, bool> {
    string m_id;

    find_by_id(const string &id) : m_id(id) { }
    bool operator()(const student &s) const {
        return s.id == m_id;
    }
};

it = std::find_if(temp_info.begin(), temp_info.end(), find_by_id(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement your own find function, to get the id from the string, because when reading the whole string and save it, id is in middle of string.

try to have a data structure that contain all information for each line, so accessing the id is easier to find

Answer (score 0):

There is a find_if for stl which can be useful

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/

You are given a full string and you have a student id which is the second column you can get the second column using a stringtokenizer and compare that with student id abd return true or false

Comment: Oh...I am really a new in cpp, so...I haven't finished the basic learning...I'll learn STL after finishing the base. And thank you for your help!